# admob free and firebase-analytics ionic1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, admob, firebase-analytics

I have a ionic1 application that currently using [crodova-plugin-admob-free](https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free) and I am trying to add [cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics)
However after I get the error when trying to build application this is the error I am getting

```
In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[11.0.
  4]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
```

I tried to search for the solution however failed, lemme know if you encountered this issue before

here is build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "com.appodeal.plugin/sgx_idx_asx_nyse-dependency_fix.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*

    ELSE NOTHING! DON'T MESS WITH THE VERSION CODE IF YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

    else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
      def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }
    */

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:adcolony", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:adcolony", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_appwall", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_appwall", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_common", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_common", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_interstitial", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_interstitial", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_mvdownloads", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_mvdownloads", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_mvnative", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_mvnative", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_nativeex", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_nativeex", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_offerwall", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_offerwall", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_playercommon", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_playercommon", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_reward", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_reward", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_videocommon", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_videocommon", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    debugCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_videofeeds", configuration: "debug")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    releaseCompile(project(path: "com.appodeal.plugin:mobvista_videofeeds", configuration: "release")){
        exclude module:("CordovaLib")
    }
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10+"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.3.+"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning' || task.name == 'validateSigningRelease') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

and my config.xml

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="id" version="1.1.7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>appnamer</name>
    <description>
        appname.
    </description>
    <author email="someemail@gmail.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      name
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preferance name="android-usesCleartextTraffic" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4500" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="750" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://quotes.wsj.com/" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook" spec="^0.2.2">
        <variable name="FACEBOOK_DISPLAY_NAME" value="VIndex Stock Screener" />
        <variable name="FACEBOOK_APP_ID" value="252597731903503" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.116:8100" />
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="^2.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="^0.27.0">
        <variable name="ADMOB_APP_ID" value="ca-app-pub-0432229319031959~4253776269" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="8.1.0" />
</widget>
```